# WordPress menu - Show a pop-up box when clicked

Tags: wordpress, nav

[image]

I would like to click or hover on the links on the right and have it bring up the associated page/post as a pop-up. I have used the primary WordPress nav menu, that can be edited from the dashboard. But WordPress menus contain either pages, links, or categories. What one of those three should I use in the menu, to bring up an associated pop-up? The pop-up will look like this:

[image]

I thought a post would be a good one. A page will take the user to a new page which is not really what we want. We want it all to stay on this page.

Answer (score 2):

You should use "lightbox gone wild" from [this link](http://www.particletree.com/features/lightbox-gone-wild/). I have used in my site and 
   it is working very fine. There are many features in it like, next-previous button, close 
   button, open popup inside popup. For any help you can contact me. I have used it in [my site](http://tell.com.sg/frances/frances/frances-rendition-of-anti-ageing/)

Comment: Thanks. One of the requirements is really that the admin of the wordpress site can add in more menu items with pop-ups from the dashboard in wordpress. I'm not sure this option will let that happen. Maybe I should add word press pages that all look the same except the writing in the middle from the dashboard

Comment: Firstly clear me that menu is what? pages, posts, category or what?

Comment: Not sure. I want to allow the admin to add a post or page or anything that will display how I have shown. Maybe it is impossible.

Comment: Everything is possible if you have talent. Simply create pages and list in your right sidebar. create template for each pages. and create template for page where your menu is listed that is as above. and use like this. <a href="form.html" class="lbOn">Email This</a>. Here form.html will be your dynamic path of popup pages in loop and "Email This " is pages title in loop. do not remove class="lbOn". Try to start. I am with you.

Comment: Thanks :) I sort of follow. I have done something similar I think? I have created the pages from the dashboard. I have made every new page have the template as above. When I click the link, it goes to the page with the correct text in the box. Is this similar to what you thought?

Comment: yes, now in main template call all pages link. May be this link is useful for this purpose http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: Thanks. I used http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu. It seems to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57543/discussion-between-arshad-hussain-and-user3164083).